# react-router v5 BrowserRouter basename changes but url doesn't

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
function App() {
   return (
         <main>
            <Switch>
               <Route path={`/:lng(en)?/blog/:slug`} component={BlogPost} />
               <Route path={`/:lng(en)?/blog`} component={Blog} />
               <Route path={`/:lng(en)?/gallery`} component={Gallery} />
               <Route exact path={`/:lng(en)?`} component={Home} />
            </Switch>
         </main>
   );
}

function MyRouter(props) {
   const { lang, setLang } = useContext(LanguageContext);
   return <BrowserRouter basename={lang}>{props.children}</BrowserRouter>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <LanguageProvider>
      <MyRouter>
            <App />
      </MyRouter>
   </LanguageProvider>,
   document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

This is my **index.jsx** file and it's working. The problem I have here is `BrowserRouter`'s `basename` changes according to the context, but it doesn't affect the URL.

for example, the first address is `site.com/base/some-page`. Using context, the value of `lang` changes correctly, and "react DevTools" says the `basename` value of `BrowserRouter` has changed too. Now, when I navigate, the address should be `site.com/new-base/another-page`; but it remains `site.com/base/another-page` and the URL doesn't change.

What should I do?